# Making sure that a C# form has focus when it should

Tags: c#, forms, focus, webbrowser-control

I am a fairly new to Visual C# but have coded in Delphi for a long time.  I have created a form that has a simple panel that is hidden unless you type in a particular key on the keyboard (I do have "KeyPreview" set for true for the form and I am using the KeyDown event to handle determining if the correct key was pressed and to make the panel visible/invisible).  Just beneath the panel is a webBrowser component.

What is happening is as follows:

When my form initially starts, I have code for the "Shown" event that makes sure the form has focus initially:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Focused)
    {
        Focus();
    }
}
```

When the form is focused at this point, my code for detecting the proper keystroke to get the panel to appear or disappear works fine.

Here is where things get strange and I'm not sure of what to do.  There are two parts I am dealing with for what is wrong:

1. If I click on another form and then on the caption bar of my form again to get focus on my form and try a keystroke, the keystroke detection does not work.  However, if I click on another form and then back on my form one more time, the keystroke detection for the form does work.  What can I do to make sure that this works each time my from has focus again?
2. If I click on the web browser component within my own form, the KeyDown code for the form no longer gets enacted.  Even if I click on the caption bar for the form, the KeyDown event does not work.  What do I need to do to assure that, if a component within my form is clicked, my form will still respond for the KeyDown event?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Can you show the code for your caption bar?

Comment: That's just it.  I don't have any code for the caption bar.  I just have code for a KeyDown event for the form itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say why your caption bar seems to be intercepting key events. It may be that various components on the form can have focus and thus capture keyboard events. I know the web browser control works this way.  You may consider capturing keyboard events globally.

I saw something on [Codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) that shows how to do this. I hope this helps.

They use UserActivityHooks.

```
UserActivityHook actHook;
void MainFormLoad(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   actHook= new UserActivityHook(); // crate an instance

// hang on events

   actHook.OnMouseActivity+=new MouseEventHandler(MouseMoved);
   actHook.KeyDown+=new KeyEventHandler(MyKeyDown);
   actHook.KeyPress+=new KeyPressEventHandler(MyKeyPress);
   actHook.KeyUp+=new KeyEventHandler(MyKeyUp);
}
```

As for the webbrowser control, of course it is going to interecept keyboard events. Users often have to enter text in forms and developers often code javascript on webpages to specifically hook into keyboard events. So the webbrowser control must be able to capture those.